# Javascript replace string function

Tags: javascript, replace

I have a script I'm trying to write which takes a string and finds the dmcode  then sends it to a function to format it correctly then returns the value. This seems to work but I can't get the replace function to work on the string calling it. This has got to be easy but everything I've tried has resulted in errors.

Your help is appreciated.
Max

```
function scrubDMC(DM){
var dmcode = DM;
 for (var i = 0; i < dmcode.length; i++) {

   DMC = dmcode[i];
   match = DMC.match(/modelIdentCode="(.*?)"/im);
   if (match !== null) {
     var modelIdentCode = match[1];
   }

   match = DMC.match(/systemDiffCode="(.*?)"/im);
   if (match !== null) {
     var systemDiffCode = match[1];
   }

   match = DMC.match(/\ssubSystemCode="(.*?)"/im);
   if (match !== null) {
     var subSystemCode = match[1];
   }

   match = DMC.match(/subSubSystemCode="(.*?)"/im);
   if (match !== null) {
     var subSubSystemCode = match[1];
   }

}
 var sFileName = "DMC-" + modelIdentCode +"-"+ systemDiffCode +"-"+ systemCode + "-" + subSystemCode + subSubSystemCode + "-" + assyCode +"-"+ disassyCode + disassyCodeVariant +"-" + infoCode +infoCodeVariant +"-" +itemLocationCode;

 console.log("sFileName : " + sFileName);

 return sFileName;
 }
```

Code calling the function that isn't working

```
var readyWarn2 = readyWarn.replace(/<symbol infoEntityIdent=".*?"\/>/ig, "");
var dmcode = readyWarn2.match(/<dmcode.*?>/ig);
scrubDMC(dmcode);
readyWarn2.replace(dmcode, sFileName);
```

Comment: Your last call to `replace()` doesn't do anything with the result.  Is that the one you're asking about?

Comment: Yes it doesn't replace the dmcode. but when I test the function the dmcode did get transformed

Comment: How have you confirmed that it doesn't replace it?  Are you observing the output anywhere?  As an example, look 3 lines above it, where you are capturing the output from a call to `.replace()`.

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last line needs to be

```
readyWarn2 = readyWarn2.replace(dmcode, sFileName);
```

Javascript strings can't be changed, so `String.replace()` returns a new string value.